Is Vert.x Web templ Pebble really compatible to io.peppletemplates>>pepple
I just want to update our pebble version to the new "io.pebbletemplates:pebble". It seems it doesn't work together with "io.vertx:vertx-web-templ-pebble"
It claims about the namespace of pebble:

old Namespace: com.mitchellbosecke
new Namespace: io.pebbletemplates

Is there a way work together with the new artifact of pebble?
I updated:
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-web-templ-pebble</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.9</version>
</dependency>

It depends on:
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
  <artifactId>pebble</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>

But it doesn't fit together. It seems Vert.x uses the old Namespace.
